# Sentry/Raven in reusable libraries

Tags: python, sentry

My organization is in the process of open sourcing several python libraries which we've written internally. Since we use Sentry on all our projects, most all of these codebases have references to [Raven](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/raven) for logging messages and exceptions. We're debating what to do about this:

1. Leave in references to Raven. Downside is that Raven becomes a hard-dependency even for people not using it.
2. Remove Raven. Downside is that we lose data we had been collecting thus far.
3. Wrap raven in an adapter that checks if the library is installed, and if not, simple does nothing.

I think option 3 is probably the best bet, but I'm wondering, are there any options I'm overlooking? Has someone else solved this problem before in a better way?

Comment: Hi, I'm Eric from Sentry. This sounds awesome, I'd love to learn a bit more about what you're open sourcing and if we can be helpful in the process.

Comment: You might be able to get very useful answers at [Open Source](http://opensource.stackexchange.com) as well :)

Comment: Realized I forgot to leave email: eric@getsentry.com